# How can i change a link hover color in laravel 5.2

Tags: css

I want to change hover color in laravel 5.2
I'm try but can't.
Here is my `link`

```
<div class="classname">
     <h4 align="center" class="well"><a  href="{{ url('course_materials').'/'.$classrooms[0]->id}}"><b>Course Materials<b></a></h4>
</div>
```

Here is my `css`

```
div.classname a:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: try  **color: green !important;**

Comment: color: green !important; not working.

Comment: add all your codes in a jsfiddle post the link here...the piece of code you post in your question is working fine..it could be something in your css script or somewehere that is affecting that hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: 
.classname a:hover { color: green } 
OR 
change class to your link

1. a href="your link" class="classname" >....  < / a >
2. .classname a:hover { color: green }

I hope it work!

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes as below in your css codes and it will work for you.

```
<div class="classname">
    <h4 align="center" class="well"><a  href="{{ url('course_materials').'/'.$classrooms[0]->id}}"><b>Course Materials<b></a></h4>
</div>
```

In you css make changes and replace the code with lines below:

```
.classname a:hover {
    color: green;
}
```